# Date Sorting in XSLT 3.0

Tags: sorting, date, xslt

I have a date field in XML which will always be in MMDDYYYY format. I am trying to sort using the date by the following code:

```
     <xsl:sort select="format-date(Date, '[M01][D01][Y0001]')"/>
```

Need help in resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first bit of advice is to use international standards - they exist for a reason.

If you can't use international standards in your stored data, then convert the data to international standard form for processing. So you want a function in your stylesheet

```
<xsl:function name="f:us-date-to-iso" as="xs:date">
   <xsl:param name="us-date" as="xs:string"/> <!-- format MMDDYYYY -->
   <xsl:sequence select-"xs:date(replace($us-date, '(..)(..)(....)', '$3-$1-$2'))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then you can sort using `<xsl:sort select="f:us-date-to-iso(Date)"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Michael Key, is it possible to avoid calling the function incase Date does not appear or comes as blank?

Comment: Follow-on questions are best raised as a new question, not as a comment on an answer to a previous questioin.